# R: How do I create a vector of user inputs into my function?

Tags: r

I have this function for finding outliers. It works great, except when I make a mistake.

In that case, I need to go all the way back to the beginning.

The function plots the distribution for each variable in a data frame and asks for user input on the indexes related to the outliers.

This is the section of the function. It is embedded in a for loop.

```
    #mark the extreme outliers, the rest are reasonable outliers
    A <- colnames(df_out_id[i])

    P <- readline(prompt="Would you like to see the full table of outliers? (enter to skip): ")
    if(P == 0 | length(P) > 1){print("Reminder: the following questions identify outliers")}
    if(P == "y" | P == "Y"){View(Outliers)}

    W <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter the index for first Extreme value on the lower limit (if none, enter 0): "))
    Q <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter the index for final Extreme value on the upper limit (if none, enter 0): "))

    col <- df_out_id[i]
    df_out_id[i] <- sapply(col[[1]], function(x){
      if(Q>1 & x %in% Outliers$curr_column[1:Q]) return('Extreme')
      if(W>1 & x %in% Outliers$curr_column[W:length(Outliers$curr_column)]) return('Extreme')
      else if (x %in% Outliers$curr_column[Q+1:length(Outliers$curr_column)]) return('Reasonable')
      else return('Non-Outlier')
    })

  }

  #return a dataframe with outlier status, excluding the outlier ID columns
  summary(df_out_id)
  return(df_out_id[1:(length(names(df_out_id))-3)])
}
```

The full function is GetOutliers(), described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272924/how-do-i-speed-up-my-function-specifically-the-ggplot-commands).

Is there a way to save any inputs to a vector and then print them at the end of the function?

Specifically, print them when the function successfully completes or in the case it is aborted along the way.